# Maximize $f(x,y)=x+y$ subject to $\sqrt{4-2 x}+\sqrt{4-2 y}=\sqrt{x y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Given that $x,y \in [0,2]$ find the maximum value of $x+y$ if $$\sqrt{4-2 x}+\sqrt{4-2 y}=\sqrt{x y}$$

Looking for an elementary approach. No Lagrange multipliers please.

My try:

I tried using CS inequality:

$$\sqrt{4-2x}+\sqrt{4-2y}\leq \sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{8-2(x+y)}$$
$\implies$
$$\sqrt{xy} \le \sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{8-2(x+y)}$$
But not able to proceed?

Comment: Well, since the constraint and test functions are symmetric, it's natural to look at the solution with $x=y$.  Barring arithmetic error, that comes to $x=y=4(\sqrt2 -1)$. Anyway, I'd start there.

Comment: I want to suggest the following **hint:**

Let, $x=2\sin ^2\alpha$ and $y=2\cos^2\beta$, such that $\alpha,\beta\in\left[0,\frac {\pi}{2}\right]$. This gives

$$\cos \alpha+\sin \beta=\sin\alpha\cos\beta $$

Then we need to find

$$\max\{\sin ^2\alpha +\cos^2\beta\}$$

and angle sum and difference identities an general [this][https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities] can help

$$\sin^2\alpha =\frac{1 - \cos2 \alpha}{2}, \cos^2\beta =\frac {\cos2\beta +1}{2}$$

Comment: @lulu What do You think about trigo approach?

Comment: @nonstudent  Interesting.  Does it resolve to give the symmetric result?  (I'd be somewhat surprised if the symmetric result isn't optimal, though it does happen).

Comment: @lulu I added it as a comment because I don't know for sure if it works.  Maybe it could work...

Comment: @nonstudent  I'd say it was worth a try.

Comment: @lulu How do you add the link in the comments?  I couldn't do that in my comment.  Can you give an example, please..?

Comment: I see an $x + y$ and an $\sqrt[2]{xy}$ and my brain immediately goes to AM GM. I can't see where it can be used or how, but it feels like one can use it.

Comment: Use parentheses instead of brackets to embed the link.  the form is [...](...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remark*: Alternatively, we can use the substitutions $\sqrt{4 - 2x} = u, \sqrt{4-2y} = v$.

---

From $\sqrt{4-2x} + \sqrt{4-2y} = \sqrt{xy}$, we have
$$(8 - 2x - 2y) + 2\sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)} \ge xy$$
or
$$4(8 - 2x - 2y) + 8\sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)} \ge 4xy$$
or
$$4(8 - 2x - 2y) + 8\sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)} \ge (4-2x)(4-2y) - 16 + 8x + 8y$$
or
$$ 64 - 16x - 16y \ge \Big(4 - \sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)}\Big)^2$$
or
$$\sqrt{64 - 16x - 16y} \ge 4 - \sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)}$$
or
$$\sqrt{64 - 16x - 16y} + \sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)} \ge 4.$$

Using $\sqrt{(4-2x)(4-2y)} \le \frac{4-2x + 4 - 2y}{2}$, we have
$$\sqrt{64 - 16x - 16y} + \frac{4-2x + 4 - 2y}{2} \ge 4$$
or
$$\sqrt{64 - 16(x + y)} \ge x + y$$
or
$$64 - 16(x + y) \ge (x + y)^2$$
which results in
$$x + y \le 8\sqrt 2 - 8.$$

Also, if $x = y = 4\sqrt 2 - 4$, we have $x, y\in [0, 2]$
and $\sqrt{4-2x} + \sqrt{4-2y} = \sqrt{xy}$
and $x + y = 8\sqrt 2 - 8$.

Thus, the maximum of $x + y$
is $8\sqrt 2 - 8$.